# Azure B2C Custom Policy: Insecure RestfulProvider

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

Is it possible to have a custom B2C policy call a REST API that uses a self-signed cert?

Currently, using the `Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProviderRestfulProvider` to call a HTTPS REST API that uses a self-signed cert, I get the following errors in the Application Insight logs...

```
The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.

The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
```

Is there a metadata item I can use to have it ignore TLS verification?
If not, how to I add my cert to a B2C trust store?

Comment: Hi @anschoewe. What happens if you add the metadata item?: `<Item Key="AllowInsecureAuthInProduction">true</Item>`

Comment: Hi @ChrisPadgett, I already have that set to true.  Sadly I still get the same error message.